# How to write to memory location reserved for struct

Tags: c++, c, struct

I have a struct:

```
struct foo{
  uint8_t i1 : 4;
  uint8_t i2 : 4;
  uint8_t i3 : 4;
  uint8_t i4 : 4;
}
```

Now, I have a 16-bit integer (call it a) that I want to write to the memory location for this struct, without having to do:

```
foo1.i1 = (uint8_t)a>>12;
foo1.i2 = (uint8_t)a>>8;
foo1.i3 = (uint8_t)a>>4;
foo1.i4 = (uint8_t)a;
```

Is there an option to just write the 16 bits to the memory location of foo1. Something like:

```
*(*uint16_t)&foo1 = a;
```

Comment: First question: why are you using bitfields?

Comment: A decent compiler realizes what you're doing - this may be premature optimization. Of course, if the compiler reverses the layout (bit order in a byte is unspecified) then your cast is just wrong.

Comment: @Neil What's wrong with using bitfields?

Comment: @ πάντα  Non-portable, slow.

Comment: You  already answered your own question; other for the fact that it should be uint16_t* and not *uint16_t, it'll do what you want. But doing that may break your code in the future, if the struct changes for instance and you forget to change these direct access instances.

Comment: @Neil Maybe an XY problem.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:avx2]?

Comment: Hi there, thanks so much everyone. This is an optimization I have to do for a class project on numerical performance code.

Comment: Tagged AVX because I have to write entire AVX register to 8 of these structs.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should make sure that this is an optimization that you need to do - done incorrectly, you could run into problems concerning alignment, byte-ordering, etc. As such, you'll want to use a profiler to examine the code performance and determine if this is one of the areas that's consuming a significant amount of processor time. Remember [what Donald Knuth wrote](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization):

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.

Once you've confirmed that this is a useful optimization to make, then you should be able to do it in a few ways. One of them is to use `memcpy`...

```
memcpy(&foo1, &a, sizeof(foo1));
```

Alternatively, you could make `foo1` a `union` type with a `uint16_t` member and write to that...

```
union {
    struct foo f;
    uint16_t u;
} foo1;
foo1.u = a;
```

Comment: Do note the type punning via a union in C++ is undefined behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's true, but it's not just an issue with the `union` approach - basically anything that involves "I'm going to ignore the C++ types of these objects and treat them as raw memory" is going to have similar portability concerns (hence why you should prefer the portable, non-optimized version until you have good reason to believe that hand-optimizing it will make a meaningful difference).

Comment: Adding a note that we should use profilers to measure *most significant bottlenecks*; these are what we should target when optimising a program, which implies that we need *an actual solution* to optimise... and then, once we've applied the optimisation, we should *profile again* to ensure that we actually optimised. Any other method is mere *guesswork*, and *guesswork* could result in *slower* code!

Comment: @BenS. in C++ the memcpy version is correct and the union version is undefined behaviour

Comment: Great! Thanks! I have to do this to write an entire AVX register to the memory locations for 8 structs, so this is great help!

Comment: @user227837 Wait, are we talking about interacting with a structure that represents a memory-mapped device? Because there could be additional complications involved there.